# Devexpress MVC Multiple Single Radio Buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, radio-group

I'm using Devexpress to render multiple radio buttons.

I do **not** want to use `Html.DevExpress().RadioButtonListFor()` unless i could change the custom default rendering.

RadioButtonListFor currently renders as:

[image]

this is quite nice, **but i would like to add some other elements behind the radio buttons**. e.g.

[image]

I have no clue how i could achieve this behavior.

**What i have tried so far:**

Insert multiple single Devexpress radio buttons

```
Html.DevExpress().RadioButton(s =>
{
    s.Name = "Name1";
    s.GroupName = "LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift";
}).Render();

Html.DevExpress().RadioButton(s =>
{
    s.Name = "Name2";
    s.GroupName = "LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift";
}).Render();
```

But this is not binding to my ViewModel which looks like this

```
public class OfferViewModel
{   
    public OfferViewModel()
    {
        LieferungLeistungen = new OfferLieferungLeistungenViewModel();
    }

    public OfferLieferungLeistungenViewModel LieferungLeistungen { get; set; }
}

public class OfferLieferungLeistungenViewModel
{
    public int SelectedUeberschrift { get; set; }
}
```

Currently the generated HTML looks like:

```
<span class="dxichCellSys dxeBase_MetropolisBlueCat dxeTAR" id="Name1">
    <span class="dxEditors_edtRadioButtonUnchecked_MetropolisBlueCat dxeIRadioButton_MetropolisBlueCat dxichSys" id="Name1_S_D">
        <span class="dxKBSW">
            <input id="Name1_S" name="Name1" value="I" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="opacity: 0; width: 0; height: 0; position: relative; background-color: transparent; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0; font-size: 0pt;">
        </span>
    </span>
</span>

<span class="dxichCellSys dxeBase_MetropolisBlueCat dxeTAR" id="Name2">
    <span class="dxEditors_edtRadioButtonUnchecked_MetropolisBlueCat dxeIRadioButton_MetropolisBlueCat dxichSys" id="Name2_S_D">
        <span class="dxKBSW">
            <input id="Name2_S" name="Name2" value="I" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="opacity: 0; width: 0; height: 0; position: relative; background-color: transparent; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0; font-size: 0pt;">
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

If i change the markup to:

```
Html.DevExpress().RadioButton(s =>
{
    s.Name = "LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift";
    s.GroupName = "LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift";
}).Render();

Html.DevExpress().RadioButton(s =>
{
    s.Name = "LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift";
    s.GroupName = "LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift";
}).Render();
```

it gives an exception (of course):

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   DevExpress.Web.Mvc5.v15.2.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An extension with
>   'LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift' name already rendered.

Comment: What is the actual html generated by the use of your `Html.DevExpress().RadioButton()` method?

Comment: Updated question with generated html code. Hm. No name for "LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift" but why?

Comment: Yes that would not bind because `name` attributes are `Name1` and `Name2` respectively - the would need to be `LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift`. Also the `value` attributes are identical and not typeof `int`. Perhaps it needs to be `s.Name="LieferungLeistungen.SelectedUeberschrift"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke this gives an exception. See updated Question

Comment: You would think that `GroupName` would add the correct name attribute but obviously not.